# Scala Java Error: value filter is not a member of java.util.Map. Works outside of class

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I'm trying to refactor some Scala code in Eclipse and run into this compilation error:

**value filter is not a member of java.util.Map**

```
import java.io.File
import com.typesafe.config._

class ConfigLoader  {

    def parseFile( confFile : File) {
        val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(confFile).root().unwrapped();        
        for((k,v) <- conf; (dk, dv) = (k, v.toString())) config.param += (dk -> dv);        
    }
```

(config is an object with "param" being a Map of String:String)

This code was pull exactly from Main() where it worked fine like so:

```
object Main extends Logging {        

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        //code cropped for readability. 
        //config.param["properties"] is absolute path to a passed-in properties file. 

        val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new java.io.File(config.param("properties"))).root().unwrapped();

        for((k,v) <- conf; (dk, dv) = (k, v.toString())) config.param+=(dk -> dv);
```

as you can see the code is exactly the same. I've imported the same libraries. All i'm doing different in main now is instantiating `ConfigLoader` and calling it like so:

`cfgLoader.parseFile(config.param("properties"))`

**Any ideas what's causing the error just by moving it to a class?**

I've googled the error and it seems to be pretty generic.

Comment: Usually when I see something like this I let the scala compiler decide if there's something wrong, IDEs cannot be trusted completely because they are still fairly young and have some bugs, try to compile your code from console and see if the error keeps popping up, also please add the error to your question.

Comment: Have you checked the imports in the file where you've defined `Main`?

Comment: @Ende Eclipse gives problems when there's errors (warning everytime you compile,unable to find main(), etc) 

yes, they are the same imports.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Turns out I was missing a tricky import after all:

`import collection.JavaConversions._`

not to be confused with `JavaConverters._` which I did have.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This is depreciated in Scala 2.12, use JavaConvertes and .asScala  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38320909/429476

Comment: it doesn't really explain the problem, only give a solution

Comment: @Juh_ the problem was I was using the wrong library.

Comment: Do solve the problem on Scala 2.11!   Could someone explain it?

Comment: @ShuaiLiu Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are using a java Map which doesn't implement the monad api (map, flatMap, ...) required to use scala for-comprehension.

More specifically, in your example, the compiler is complaining about missing `.filter` method. This is because you unpack each item of the map: `(key, value) <- monad` instead of a direct assignment, such as `entry <- monad`. But even if you did use direct assignment, it would complain about missing `.map` or `.flatMap`. See [this answer to "how to make you own for-comprehension compliant scala monad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35761235/1206998) for details on the required api.

The simplest solution to your problem is to convert you java map into scala map using:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

...
for((k,v) <- conf.asScala) ...
```

The import includes implicit that add the `.asScala` method to java map