# How to make your own for-comprehension compliant scala monad?

Tags: scala, monads

I want to implement my own for-comprehension compatible monads and functors in Scala.

Let's take two stupid monads as an example. One monad is a state monad that contains an "Int" that you can map or flatmap over.

```
val maybe = IntMonad(5)
maybe flatMap( a => 3 * ( a map ( () => 2 * a ) ) )
// returns IntMonad(30)
```

Another monad takes does function composition like so...

```
val func = FunctionMonad( () => println("foo") )
val fooBar = func map ( () => println("bar") )
fooBar()
// foo
// bar
// returns Unit
```

The example may have some mistakes, but you get the idea.

I want to be able to use these two different types of made up Monads inside a for-comprehension in Scala. Like this:

```
val myMonad = IntMonad(5)
for {
    a <- myMonad
    b <- a*2
    c <- IntMonad(b*2)
} yield c    
// returns IntMonad(20)
```

I am not a Scala master, but you get the idea

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For a type to be used within a for-comprehension, you really only need to define `map` and `flatMap` methods for it that return instances of the same type. Syntactically, the for-comprehension is transformed by the compiler into a series of `flatMap`s followed by a final `map` for the `yield`. As long as these methods are available with the appropriate signature, it will work.

I'm not really sure what you're after with your examples, but here is a trivial example that is equivalent to `Option`:

```
sealed trait MaybeInt {
    def map(f: Int => Int): MaybeInt
    def flatMap(f: Int => MaybeInt): MaybeInt
}

case class SomeInt(i: Int) extends MaybeInt {
    def map(f: Int => Int): MaybeInt = SomeInt(f(i))
    def flatMap(f: Int => MaybeInt): MaybeInt = f(i)
}

case object NoInt extends MaybeInt {
    def map(f: Int => Int): MaybeInt = NoInt
    def flatMap(f: Int => MaybeInt): MaybeInt = NoInt
}
```

I have a common trait with two sub-types (I could have as many as I wanted, though). The common trait `MaybeInt` enforces each sub-type to conform to the `map`/`flatMap` interface.

```
scala> val maybe = SomeInt(1)
maybe: SomeInt = SomeInt(1)

scala> val no = NoInt
no: NoInt.type = NoInt

for {
  a <- maybe
  b <- no
} yield a + b

res10: MaybeInt = NoInt

for {
  a <- maybe
  b <- maybe
} yield a + b

res12: MaybeInt = SomeInt(2)
```

Additionally, you can add `foreach` and `filter`. If you want to also handle this (no yield):

```
for(a <- maybe) println(a)
```

You would add `foreach`. And if you want to use `if` guards:

```
for(a <- maybe if a > 2) yield a
```

You would need `filter` or `withFilter`.

A full example:

```
sealed trait MaybeInt { self =>
    def map(f: Int => Int): MaybeInt
    def flatMap(f: Int => MaybeInt): MaybeInt
    def filter(f: Int => Boolean): MaybeInt
    def foreach[U](f: Int => U): Unit
    def withFilter(p: Int => Boolean): WithFilter = new WithFilter(p)

    // Based on Option#withFilter
    class WithFilter(p: Int => Boolean) {
        def map(f: Int => Int): MaybeInt = self filter p map f
        def flatMap(f: Int => MaybeInt): MaybeInt = self filter p flatMap f
        def foreach[U](f: Int => U): Unit = self filter p foreach f
        def withFilter(q: Int => Boolean): WithFilter = new WithFilter(x => p(x) && q(x))
    }
}

case class SomeInt(i: Int) extends MaybeInt {
    def map(f: Int => Int): MaybeInt = SomeInt(f(i))
    def flatMap(f: Int => MaybeInt): MaybeInt = f(i)
    def filter(f: Int => Boolean): MaybeInt = if(f(i)) this else NoInt
    def foreach[U](f: Int => U): Unit = f(i)
}

case object NoInt extends MaybeInt {
    def map(f: Int => Int): MaybeInt = NoInt
    def flatMap(f: Int => MaybeInt): MaybeInt = NoInt
    def filter(f: Int => Boolean): MaybeInt = NoInt
    def foreach[U](f: Int => U): Unit = ()
}
```

Comment: Would it be better to use the Scallaz Monad type instead of defining your own?

Comment: `filter` api is also require to "unpack" the monad items. For example if you use a MaybeAB similar to the MaybeInt but for a `case class AB(a: Int, b: Int)`, filter is required to do `for( AB(a,b) <- maybAB) ...`