# How to make my custom class available for `<-`?

Tags: scala

I don't know how to search for `<-` online, or what the symbol is called.

I have a class

```
class MyClass(collection: List[A]) {}
```

And I want to be able to do:

```
val bar = new MyClass(???)
for {
  foo <- bar
} yield ???
```

And iterate through the element of `collection`.

What do I need to `override` ?

I already saw [How to make your own for-comprehension compliant scala monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761043/how-to-make-your-own-for-comprehension-compliant-scala-monad) but I don't understand how to make it yield my `collection` .

Edit:
Thanks to all the answers below, I was able to make some progress.

By implementing:

```
def map(f: A => A): MyClass
```

and

```
def flatMap(f: A => MyClass): MyClass
```

There is no issue with using it within a for-comprehension.

However, the type of `foo`, from the first use case, is `Any` instead of being `A`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make your own for-comprehension compliant scala monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761043/how-to-make-your-own-for-comprehension-compliant-scala-monad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single generator, `<-`, your class needs a `map()` method.

```
class MyClass {
  def map(f :Int => Int) :Int = 42
}
val bar = new MyClass
for {
  foo <- bar
} yield foo  //42
```

With a 2nd generator it also needs a `flatMap()` method.

```
class MyClass {
  def map(f :MyClass => MyClass) :MyClass = new MyClass
  def flatMap(f :MyClass => MyClass) :Int = 3
}
val bar = new MyClass
for {
  foo <- bar  //map from MyClass to MyClass
  baz <- foo  //flatMap from MyClass to Int
} yield baz   //3
```

These are, of course, bogus and meaningless implementations used just to demonstrate the concept.

**EDIT**

As to your comment:

```
class HiddenCollection[A](mything :List[A]) {
  def map[B](f :A => B) :List[B] = mything.map(f)
}
for {
  x <- new HiddenCollection(List('c', 'y', 'q'))
} yield x.toUpper  //res0: List[Char] = List(C, Y, Q)
```

Comment: My use case is `class HiddenCollection(mything: List[A])` and I want to iterate through the `mything` when i use `<-` on `new HiddenCollection(...)` . I don't understand how I would do that.

Answer (score 2):

you need to at least implement `map` and possibly `flatMap` and `filter` as for is syntactic sugar around it see [the documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html)

something like

```
   class MyClass[A](collection: List[A]){
      def map[B](f: A => B):List[B] = collection.map(f)
    }
```

Comment: What is the prototype of the methods to implement ?

Comment: Maybe consult Option https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html The rewrite is syntactic, so signature is flexible.

Comment: I don't see any source code for the `map` and `flatMap` method

Comment: you asked about the prototype?! - anyway from the comment on the other answer it seems your actual question is not generic so I suggest you ask exactly want you want