# get long value from scala.Option in java

Tags: java, scala-option

I have a `Option<Object>` from which i am trying to get long value. But this does not work. I tried the below steps but could not get the value as it shows compiler error. Please help.

```
//#1
Option<Object> expireTimestamp = offsetAndMetadata.expireTimestamp();
expireTimestamp.getOrElse(0L);
```

Also tried

```
Option<Object> expireTimestamp = offsetAndMetadata.expireTimestamp();
expireTimestamp.getOrElse(new Long(0));


//#2
Option<Long> expireTimestamp = (Option<Long>) offsetAndMetadata.expireTimestamp();
```

**The method getOrElse(Function0) in the type Option is not applicable for the arguments (long)**

Comment: I think @JoopEggen is on the money. `getOrElse` takes a lazy value, i.e. a Producer function with no parameters, not the value directly.

Comment: Maybe you should use the Java converter library to change it to a Java Optional first and take it from there: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38325656/14955

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As, commented by Thilo, I tried the below code and it worked

```
offsetAndMetadata.expireTimestamp().getOrElse(() -> 0L)
```