# How can I access a method which return Option object?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have to call method which returns `Option[List[Obj]]`.

After I call I need to iterate the List and print the Obj attributes.

```
object Tester{
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    val ymlFilename ="some.yml";
  val entities: Option[QueryEntities] =  InputYamlProcessor.process(ymlFilename)

        for( e: QueryEntities  <- entities ){
          /// this is not working
           //How to access the columnFamily, fromData and toDate ?
        }
  }
```

Complete sample

https://gist.github.com/shatestest/fdeaba767d78e171bb6c08b359fbd1bf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most iconic way ot do it is to unwrap values with scala is to use pattern matching to unwrap the value.

```
entities match {
    case Some(queryEntities: QueryEntities) => 
      queryEntities.entities.foreach { case e =>
        println(e.columnFamily)
        println(e.fromDate.getOrElse("defaultFromDateHere")
        println(e.toDate.getOrElse("defaultToDateHere"))
      }
    case None => println("No value")
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your prompt reply but i am not able to access entity attributes in Some case. how to access them ???

Comment: I declared as   '      case class QueryEntity(columnFamily: String, fromDate: Option[String], toDate: Option[String])
case class QueryEntities(entities: List[QueryEntity])    '

Comment: What do you mean by "Cannot access to entity attributes"? If there is an entity (`case Some(entity)`), you have access to entity which is a QueryEntities? Ill add more details to the answer

Comment: sir thank you , but when I say   '  case Some(queryEntities: QueryEntities) => 
            for (e:QueryEntity <- queryEntities) { //Error  value withFilter is not a member of com.snp.helpers.Model.QueryEntities
               val columnFamName:String = e.columnFamily.toLowerCase().trim()
               val fromDate:String = e.fromDate.getOrElse("")
               val toDate:String = e.toDate.getOrElse("")      }      '

Comment: for (e:QueryEntity <- queryEntities) { //Error  value withFilter is not a member of com.snp.helpers.Model.QueryEntities   .... What does this mean sir ?

Comment: This is because there is not withFilter method in the case class, I am updating my post

Comment: You should probably open a new issue with your problem, or check on other posts, the question was "how to access to unwrap option values" which was solved :)

Comment: ...thank you sir , sure......scala is super tough compare to Java , which is pretty easy....but this also not useful....Error ... """value foreach is not a member of com.snp.helpers.Model.QueryEntities"""

Comment: My bad, I misread your previous comments, I fixed the code. I added .entities to iterate through the list of queryEntity