# How to untuple (implicit) scalaz Monad in a for-comprehension?

Tags: scala, tuples, monads, scalaz, for-comprehension

I use for-comprehension with implicit scalaz monad, but when I extract tupled data, it outputs

`value filter is not a member of type parameter M[...]`

The code looks like this:

```
implicit val monad: Monad[M] = ...
for{
  (a,b) <- getABMonad() // error: value filter is not ...
} yield a + b
```

where `getABMonad(): M[(Int, Int)]`. `M` is a type-argument, which can be several things, like Identity, EitherT, or other standard monads. I get it using `implicitly[Monad[WhatEverMonadImUsing]]` so I don't implement my-self the monad api.

[From what I understood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48298516/1206998), for-comprehension use the `filter` api to untuple data. So it seems scala.Monad doesn't provide it. I can solve the problem by writing:

```
implicit val monad: Monad[M] = ...
for{
  aAndB <- getABMonad()
  (a, b) = aAndB
} yield a + b
```

Is there a practical way to avoid this untuple line?

[scalaz 2.10-7.0.2]

Comment: This is a limitation of Scala rather than scalaz and the likes. You can look at the [better monadic for](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for) compiler plugin by Oleg.

Comment: Tx. Not what I would have hoped, but it's a valid answer I could upvote